# Notification when input field2 less then field1

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want to denied if input field2(star2) less or equal with field1(star1)
notification JS

my blade:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" name="star1" value="{{old('star1')}}" required="required" class="col-sm-5 form-control input-sm">
  </div>         
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" name="star2" value="{{old('star2')}}" required="required" class="col-sm-5 form-control input-sm">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What JavaScript framework you  are using?

Comment: i used jquery for my blade

Answer (score 0):

Here is my [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/4vf4gm2o/) for your reference:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
           $("#start2").change(function()
                                    {
                    var start2Value=this.value;
                  var start1Value=$("#start1").value;

                  if (start2Value<=start1Value)
                    alert("An invalid value has been entered.");

                });
   });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, 
but when i try input value on star1 with value "3" and star2 with value "2" alert value does not appear

Comment: As my understanding your requirement  is if input field2(star2) less or equal with field1(star1),  a notification would popup. Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#star2").change(function() {
            var start2Value=$(this).val();
            var start1Value=$("#star1").val();
            if (start2Value <= start1Value)
                     alert("An invalid value has been entered.");
       });
});
```